# $_POST and redirect with html submit button

Tags: php, html

I have a html form that has a series of radio groups along with php code that insert the radio group into a table.  The insert works if I do not have a link to the next page, but if the link is in the following :

`<form name ="input" action="demopg2.php" method="post">` does not insert but links to the next page.

`<form name ="input" action="" method ="post">` inserts the data but does not link to the next page

the submit button code is:

```
 <input type="submit"   class ="button" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Comment: blank actions are treated as "submit to self", e.g. you submit to whatever url the containing page was loaded from. In other words, you're getting EXACTLY what you asked for: default behavior.

Comment: How do I insert the data and link to the next page of the survey?

Comment: use a redirect. e.g. `process_your_form(); header('Location: address_of_next_page');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have:

- A script which can both display a form and insert submitted data
- Another script which shows the next page

You need to change the logic so that either:

- The "insert submitted data" logic is moved from the first script to the second script *or*
- The first script, if it has inserted data, redirects (with a `Location` [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)) to the second script instead of displaying the form

The second approach is generally the better one as it is more easily extended to give you a third possible output: Displaying the form with error messages if bad data is submitted.